# Generating a RDD in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have an RDD of the following type

```
JavaRDD<List<Tuple4<String, String, String, String>>> resultDocs
```

How can I generate an RDD from the above RDD  which contains just the value of first value of all the tuples in the list ?

Comment: You should clarify if your `List` is a Scala list or a Java list. The Scala solution would simply be: `rdd.flatMap(_.headOption)`

Comment: This is a Java List

Comment: Then it comes down to replacing `_.headOption` by an iterator over just the first element. You can roll your own or use `list.subList(0, Math.min(1, list.size())).iterator()`.

Comment: I need to return a List<String> from a list of Tuple4<String,String,String,String> with taking only the value of just the first paris in the list of tuples.'